Why do I import the model in the three.js, it looks dark, but it looks normal on the gltf online website


I expected both of them to look the same
here is my code
async function loadSakuracar() {
 
  const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  

  const sakuracarData = await loader.loadAsync(
    "/src/assets/models/sakuracar/RobotExpressive.glb"
  
  );

    const sakuracar = setupModel(sakuracarData);
    sakuracar.position.set(0, 0, 0);

    return {
    sakuracar,
  };
}


The difference you see is lighting, which needs to be added to your viewer. A texture environment map, or THREE.RoomEnvironment, would be good options. See this example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/2ff77e4b335e31c108aac839a07401664998c730/examples/webgl_loader_gltf_compressed.html#L57-L63
